# Installing uWSGI service on RHEL8

Tags: uwsgi, rhel

I am trying to install the uWSGI service on RHEL8. After which I should be able to do `systemctl start uwsgi`.

As far as I can tell from online resources, this should work: `yum install uwsgi` (or `dnf install uwsgi`), but gives `Error: Unable to find a match: uwsgi`. Most resources are on earlier versions of RHEL, but I have not been able to find anything specific for RHEL8.

I have enabled the EPEL repository. `yum repolist` gives:

```
repo id                                  repo name                                                      status
*epel                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                   3678
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)         8289
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)            3315
rhel-8-for-x86_64-supplementary-rpms     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - Supplementary (RPMs)       28
```

I have tried the 'manual' approach, as per https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html, but this hasn't been very successful so far either, and I would prefer to use a system package if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

A good resource to check for packages availability across repositories is [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/). From there you can see `uwsgi` is just not there yet in RHEL 8 base repositories.

I think they (RedHat) keep it for some later time to release due to its complexity in package/migration.

You can attempt at installing `uwsgi` from a paid (cheap) third-party repository (disclaimer: I am the maintainer):

```
sudo dnf install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el8-latest.rpm
sudo dnf install uwsgi
```

Notables:

- This is a rebuild of EPEL packages for EL7 (they are more tuned for RHEL so had to do only a few little tweaks to specs in order to successfully rebuild for EL8)
- I did not try those myself other than install and start `uwsgi` service (seems to work). Just did for the fun of it :)
- There is no Perl support (quite a bunch of Perl modules need to be packaged for this, way too exhausting and no fun anymore.
- If ever *they* release packaged `uwsgi` in the base repository, I don't think there should be any problem upgrading to it then. So feel free to use it as either long term or temporary solution. A full list of installable packages can be found [here](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/8/x86_64/repoview/letter_u.group.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and let you know. I don't expect to need any Perl support.

Comment: Please note, that this source REQUIRE subscribe for $50.